# Remove duplicate XML records in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I need to remove duplicate records from jQuery autocomplete. I am taking some fields from an XML sheet and passing them in, but I do not know how to make sure each record is unique and only show one of each record. 
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfZ4r.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard JavaScript [Set Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicates:

```
jQuery( "#main-input" ).autocomplete({
    source: Array.from(new Set(availableTags))
    ...
```

```js
var data = ["Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Banana"]
var set = new Set(data); // duplicates are not added to the set

// display data:
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data;
document.getElementById('set').innerHTML = Array.from(set);
```

```html
<h4>Data with duplicates:</h4>
<p id='data'></p>
<h4>Set:</h4>
<p id='set'></p>
```

Comment: Can you expand on how I implement this into the autocomplete function, please? I can't seem to get it.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use this line in your code: `source: Array.from(new Set(availableTags))`